# How can I move a "text along path" vertically?

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths, text-decorations, decorations

How can I move a "text along path" vertically? Currently, I'm using a path with modified endpoints to place the text, and then draw the actual line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (p1) at (0,0) {1};
  \node (p2) at (5,0) {2};

  \path[
    postaction={
      decorate,
      decoration={
        text along path,
        text align=center,
        text={|\small\color{blue}|My curved text}
      }
    }
  ]
  (p1.25) to [bend left=15] (p2.155);

  \draw (p1) edge[<->,bend left=15] (p2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Bonus points if the solution works regardless of the path orientation (moving the letters along the path's normal, i.e. a line perpendicular to the path).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PGF documentation [pgfmanual.pdf.gz](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), in the **Text Decorations** section, says:

> Each character is positioned using the center of its baseline. To move the text vertically (relative to the path), the additional transform key should be used.

`transform` should actually be a hyperlink to de documentation for `/pgf/decoration/transform=<transformations>`, which is in the **Positioning Decorations Relative to the To-Be-Decorate Path** section.

So if you want to just move the text vertically, use `transform={yshift=1cm}`:

```
\draw[
  <->,
  postaction={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      text along path,
      text align=center,
      transform={yshift=1cm},
      text={|\small\color{blue}|My curved text}
    }
  }
]
(p1) to [bend left=15] (p2);
```

If you want to move the text along a line perpendicular to the path, then use the `/pgf/decoration/raise` key, like so:

```
% I Increased bending and set text align=left so we can se the effect better.
\draw[
  <->,
  postaction={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      text along path,
      text align=left,
      raise=1cm,
      text={|\small\color{blue}|My rounded text}
    }
  }
]
(p1) to [bend left=100] (p2);
```

Note also the `/pgf/decoration/mirror=<boolean>` key, also described in the **Positioning Decorations Relative to the To-Be-Decorate Path** section, which puts the decoration on the other side of the path.